# Magento bundle items tab in admin showing suddenly a blank page without options

Tags: magento-1, bundled-product, products-management

I've created more than 200 bundled products and it worked always as expected. But suddenly, the bundle items tab to add the bundle options is showing a blank page. I have absolutely no idea why this happened. I cleared cache but without results. When opening an existing bundle product, it shows the bundle options. Creating a new one doesn't.

The ajax content that is loading when clicking "Bundle items" is referring to https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php/admin/admin/bundle_product_edit/form/id/15064/ and I get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Existing bundle products have the same url, other ID and getting response. I copied the website local and there this is working. So something with folder permissions, server setup, routing?

Any ideas?
[image: Blank bundle options tab]

Comment: Hmm. Any error log or report created when doing this?

Comment: I found this in the system.log: 2015-01-07T09:45:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal string offset 'value'  in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php on line 111

Comment: The above notice was an issue with php 5.4, nothing else found in the logs.

Comment: The content for that tab is loaded with ajax, the server has no response. That's why it's blank. While reindexing I also get sometimes a no response page from my browser. What could be the issue? I did a test on another server and that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a combination between Ioncube, Zend Opcache and PHP 5.4, resulting in segmentation faults for some but not all URLs related to the extension that required Ioncube.